# Firefox Slow Response To Tab Change

Tags: firefox

My system is a Dell Inspiron 15 5567 connected to a Viewsonic VG2740V (~ 68 cm diagonal) monitor.

RAM - 16 GB

CPU - i5 7xxx

GPU #0 - Integrated Intel

GPU #1 (Primary GPU) - AMD Radeon M7 R445 (Mesa driver)

Op Sys - Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

In the last week, I've noticed a weird delay in rendering the new web page when moving between tabs on Firefox. It usually needs a CTRL-ALT-DEL to get it to liven up.

This having never happened before (I've had this new monitor since ~ November 2022), I am curious as to whether it's an Ubuntu thing, a Firefox thing or a monitor issue.

I get updates to my system almost daily and install them when the prompt window opens, i.e. every 2 days.

Firefox is applied to my PC via the Flatpak package manager and updates come around once a week. I am on Mozilla-Flatpak-1   version 110.0 (stable) now.

There has always been a share of flicker when a new page opens since I got this new monitor. I'd assumed this was due to the much greater area of the new monitor versus that of the built-in monitor of the laptop that drives it.

But this delay - almost a temporary seizure - is something new to me.

Can anyone suggest a cause or remedy ?

Comment: You describe a video issue with no mention of the video card or the driver in use. Please use edit and update the question.

Comment: Are you using a lot of tabs consuming a lot of RAM, and it needed to swap some of those tabs out; and when you reactivate a tab, it needs to swap it back in?

Comment: But why did this start only in the last few days? I use no more tabs now than over the last 4 months.